# Mongo Set One Table Column as One Table's Option

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Expecting a solution for this scenario. I have two tables. table 1 'team' contains'team_name' and table 2 'players' contains 'players_name' and 'players_team'. So, Here I want to insert data into players table. If I am inserting players_team in players table it should be a valid team name which exists on team table. How can I achieve this?

Note: This can be achieved by simply checking for the value in column first, But That is not what am looking for. I know in MySQL there is a method where the value of one's can be linked someway. I want to know whether the same can be achieved with mongo and mongoose

Comment: I added a note to my question. can you please look at it

Answer (score 0):

Your answer

```
router.post('/add_player', (req, res) => {
    let teamid = req.body.teamid;
    Teams.findOne({ _id: teamid }, (err, Team) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            if (Team == null) {
                console.log("Team not found")
            } else if (Team != null) {
                console.log("Team Found")

                //Add Player
                let Data = {
                    players_team: teamid,
                    team_name: Team.team_name,//Valid team name
                    player_name: req.body.player_name,
                }
                Players(Data).save((err, SaveResult) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('player saved successfully')
                        res.status(200).send('player added successfully')
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
})
```